# Create a non-content page in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a query regarding how to create a bespoke page that doesn't warrant having any document type or content associated with it.

For example there could be several pages on a site that are so different to each other that they would effectively have to have their own template.

How does Umbraco handle cases such as these, were one would effectively have to create a NON-content page with no fields in it, and then have multiple templates for each page associated with a NON-content page or am I missing the point?

Surely not every case deserves place-holders with fields in it?

Comment: What purpose does the non-content page have? Is it purely technical?

Comment: To me content pages are only useful if 1) They are going to be multiple pages published (DRY) 2) The content could change from time to time (email address on Contact Page).  If it doesn't fall into these 2 categories it would be easier to use HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add static pages, it's probably the easiest to create an empty document type and create multiple templates for this (as you stated in the opening post). This way you're still using the Umbraco routing but can't edit any content.

Another way (depending on the technical expertise of the content editor) could be to create a document type with a html editor (I believe some 3rd party packages exist) where you can paste in the html for the page. This is less user friendly (from the view of a content editor) but you don't have to create separate templates for each page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use "Route Hijacking".

See the Link below or Google "Umbraco Route Hijacking" for details.

http://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/umbraco-core-concepts/what-is-route-hijacking-in-umbraco

Comment: I don't need the page to be server rendered just plain HTML. Thanks for the link but it seems overkill.